# Basic認証のパスワード省略方法について(ユーザー名のみのログイン方法)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Apacheの.htaccessで下記のように設定をしてから

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Only"
AuthUserFile /dirname/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

下記のように.htpasswdファイルでユーザー名のみでパスワードを省略して記載しました。

```
test:
```

なぜか上手くログインできず困っております。
ユーザー名とパスワードを.htapasswdに記載すると上手くログインできました。

なぜユーザー名だけでログインできないのか検索やApacheのドキュメントも少しみてみたのですがhtaccess/認証ページでは見つけることができませんでした。

もしわかる方がいらっしゃれば教えていただけると幸いです。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

htpasswd ファイルのパスワード文字列を平文ではなく、MD5 などのハッシュ値にするとどうでしょうか？
`htpasswd /dirname/.htpasswd test` 実行後、パスワード入力プロンプトで何も入力せずリターンキーを押下する。
または、バッチモードで `htpasswd -b /dirname/.htpasswd test ""` とします。

Comment: Taichi Yanagiyaさん

コメントありがとうございます。

下記の２つのhtpasswdコマンドを使用して試してみたのですが、やっぱり上手く設定する事ができませんでした。
```$ htpasswd -c ${PWD}/.htpasswd test```
```$ htpasswd -c -b ${PWD}/.htpasswd test ""```

ちゃんとユーザー名/パスワードの両方を入力して設定すれば認証は出来るのですが、何故でしょうか。。
認証できるという事はモジュールはロードできてるとは思うのですが、難しいですね。